# crate memory game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to make a memory game and I'm trying to figure out how to call the action `hide_text` so that the parameter will be the button I clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle

root = Tk()

a = list(range(1, 19))
a = list(a) + list(a)

shuffle(a)

def game():
    count = 0
    for i in a:
        if count == 0:
            posisonx = 0
            posisony = 0
        if count == 6:
            count = 0
            posisonx = 0
            posisony += 1
        button = Button(root,text=f' {i}  ',
                        command=lambda: hide_text())
        button.grid(row=posisony, column=posisonx)
        def hide_text(s):
            s.config(text='')
        posisonx += 1
        count += 1

game()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to solve here. One is that you can't reference a button until it has been created. The other is correctly capturing the reference once it has.

If you want to pass a command involving a reference to the button, you have to split the creation into two lines:

```
button = Button(root,text=f' {i}  ')
button.configure(command=...)
```

You need to bind `button` to the lambda that you create. There are a couple of ways to do this. If you just do `command=lambda: hide_text(button)`, all the commands will point to the *last* button you create in the loop.

One trick is to use the fact that default arguments are bound when the function is created:

```
button.configure(command=lamda s=button: hide_text(s))
```

You should take `def hide_text` outside the loop in this case.

Another way is to capture a closure using a nested function. Put this outside the loop:

```
def get_hide_text(button):
    def hide_text():
        button.config(text='')
    return hide_text
```

Then, in the loop, do

```
button.configure(command=get_hide_text(button))
```

Comment: `command=lamda(s=button): hide_text(s)\
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`


And there was an arrow pointing to the ":"

Comment: what i ineed to do?

Comment: @anonymous. Sorry, was on mobile. Updated

Comment: Note that `button = Button(root, text=f'  {i}  ', command=lambda s=button: hide_text(s))` will still raise exception *"NameError: name 'button' is not defined"*.

Comment: @acw1668. That's a good catch. Upated

Comment: @anonymous. Hopefully this fixes your issue

Comment: I dont understand what i need to do

Comment: @anonymous. Split the button setup into two lines. I show two options for the second line. The first is always `button = Button(root,text=f' {i}  ')`